# how to display youtube video and mp4 file in same project using webview iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

how to display youtube video and mp4 file in same project using uiwebview iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps these will help:

- http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html
- http://learningtheworld.eu/2009/youtube-embed/
- http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application